# Azure Global admin account password change

Tags: azure, azure-stack

Can we change Azure Global admin account password, and any impact for system?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the password. It wouldn't impact any resources at all.

Comment: Would or wouldn't ??

Comment: @ArunVinoth oops, fix it.